# Does 1,3‐dichloroallene show geometrical isomerism?

Tags: cis-trans-isomerism

Since the attached groups are present in different planes, $\ce{ClCH=C=CHCl}$ should not show geometrical isomerism, but my book say that it does. Why?

Comment: You are right, there is no cis-/trans- isomerism for allenes to speak of. Probably a typo, or the book author considers enantiomeric forms geometrical isomerism too. Feel free to provide an exact quote from your textbook alongside with bibliographical data.

Comment: Enantiomerism is a geometrical isomerism.It is so obvious that I do not check any definition. Just it is that often we intend geometrical isomerism as E/Z isomerism. Even more, isomerism of whatever forms implies a different geometry of stable molecules, though I would never call two chain isomers as geometric, as in this case it would bring more confusion than information.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar The compound shows axial chirality and hence has two enantiomers.

Answer (score 3):

This is a chiral compound; it has two enantiomers.  [This source](https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-geometric-isomer-cis-trans-604481) defines "geometrical 8somerism" as isomerism involving different geometrical arrangements, and a pair of nonsuperimposable mirror images would seem to qualify.  But in the body they talk about about *cis/trans* or *E/Z* isomers, not chiral compounds.  The latter, which applies here, should be described by more precise terms like "enantiomers".

Answer (score 3):

> Since the attached groups are present in different planes,

This is exactly why is it has geometrical isomers. Going from one chlorine to the other or hyddrogen to hydrogen involves either a right-handed or left-handed rotation. I think the images below will allow you to see this relation.

[image] [image] 
Left-handed molecule $\qquad ~~~~~\qquad$ Right-handed molecule

Although this does not apply to this case a related concept is [atropisomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atropisomer) which uses *M* or *Δ* for right-handed rotations and *P* or *Λ* for left-handed rotations which would apply to these types of molecules. This convention is also used in [coordination chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(chemistry)#In_inorganic_chemistry).